# Shortest way to evaluate an array with booleans (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I have an array with booleans in it, whats the shortest way to loop through it and get the final boolean expression?

**Example**: array with 3 elems (*true, false, true*) --> the result should be false (*true && false && true* = false)

I know I can loop through it, but is there a shorter way?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `array_sum()` and then cast the response to a boolean? Oops, sorry mis-read the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if (!in_array(false, $array)) { ...
```

Comment: I was going to suggest [array_reduce](http://php.net/array_reduce), but this is *way* shorter. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't knw php but you can

search for false in array first

if search is found 
 then result is false
else
  result is true.

Not: It's just and algorithm. not a code

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_sum($array) == count($array)) {
  // All are TRUE; 
}
else {
 // One of them is FALSE;
}
```